# How to sort object keys

Tags: reactjs, sorting, object

I currently have an object (`configuration`) that gets mapped over in order to display each item on a wrap up screen. However, I need to do a sort on the object before the map but am having trouble accessing the specific value that I need.

```
const ConfigComponentSummaryContainer = ({ configuration }) => (
    <Grid container spacing={4}>
      {Object.keys(configuration)
        .map(key => {
          const config = configuration[key];
          if (config && config.length && !restrictList.includes(config[0].component.grouping.toLowerCase())) {
            return config
              .map(c => (
                <Grid item xs={6} ref={componentRef}>
                  <ConfigComponentSummary configuration={c} />
                </Grid>
              ));
          }
          return null;
      })}
    </Grid>
  );
```

This is what the configuration object looks like in the console:
[image]

I need to grab a value (`seq`) inside of component to use for the sort. How can I can access that specific value and sort before the keys are mapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sort. You can use keys and look up the object like you do in map, or use entries where you get both the key and value.

```
Object.entries(configuration)
  .sort((a, b) => a[1][0].component.seq - b[1][0].component.seq)
  .map(([key, config]) => {});
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I was familiar with the `.sort` but using `.entries` is what did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy). It has a method `sortBy` which you should be able to use like this:

```
_.sortBy(configuration, "component.seq")
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one data structure can be used for sorting, it is Array. I suppose you need to transform you object to array sorted by `seq` in component and then use it for mapping